# How to get first index from array which is a first value of an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi im new to javascript so don't mind me!

I have this object `const obj = {'name': ['jack', 'ric'], 'age': 30}`

if i do like this `console.log(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]);` i will get `['jack', 'ric']`. How can I get only `jack` without 'ric' and quote outside?

Comment: You just need `obj.name[0]`

Comment: you can do obj['name'][0]

Comment: use `console.log(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]][0]);`

Comment: @Ivar I will update my question

Comment: @kimhong Muong can i put my comment as an answer ? i put it very first time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What about this:-**
You're using `obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];` to get the first value of `name` object, your code is almost correct you have to place one more `[0]` to make this working because you're accessing an array property in another object.

**Working e.g.**

```js
const obj = {'name': ['jack', 'ric'], 'age': 30}
// to print jack in console
console.log(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]][0]);
// to print ric in console
console.log(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]][1]);
```

Hope this will helpful for you, thank you.

Comment: *because you're calling object in another object* no they're not.

Comment: Relevant SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: @Amaanwarsi Thanks you your answer helps me! The first is also correct but the thing is I get the object from json response so i don't know the object key names. Thanks you